# Is the handle of this luggage retractable?

Tags: storage, travel

I haven't used other luggages yet.  I just got a used luggage, with brand "Embark" (I guess the one sold in Target?). I can't retract its handle or adjust its length. So is its handle retractable?   Here are some photos I have taken:

Lie it down and open it:

[image]

[image]

The bottom end:

[image]

The top end:

[image]

Let it stand up, and look at it from above

[image]

[image]

Comment: This isn't a life hack question.

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks SE. This question does not seem to be about a problem and does not require a life hack. I'm going to have to close this as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

This type of luggage does have a retractable handle. Normally the release mechanism is in the handle. It is very easy to damage the handle enough to prevent retraction, or it could have been "repaired" in a way that prevents moving the handle to its recessed position.

Comment: thanks. what do you mean by "Normally the release mechanism is in the handle. It is very easy to damage the handle enough to prevent retraction, or it could have been "repaired" in a way that prevents moving the handle to its recessed position."?

Comment: Usually there is a push button somewhere in the handle that releases the lock on the handle position. It was common (when I was travelling a lot) to see luggage repair shops make just enough of a repair to lock the handle in an extended position.

Comment: Do you have a photo of such a push button?

Comment: I do not have a picture of the release button. You could try to Google an image.